# Quitting eBay application

Tags: notifications

Is there any way to quit the eBay app, so that I stop receiving all these event notifications? I like notifications, but only when I decide to run the eBay application...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in the app directly:

> eBay app (home screen) -> settings (below *WOW* list entry) -> notifications -> none

Answer (score 5):

Since Jelly Bean (Android 4.1), it's possible to disable notifications for individual apps. Long-press on the notification and go to `App Info` or go to `Settings -> Apps` and then choose the eBay app. Uncheck the `Show Notifications` checkbox (detailed description with video [here](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57467781-285/how-to-turn-off-notifications-for-an-app-in-android-4.1-jelly-bean/)).

Notifications are most useful if an app needs your attention but is currently not in your focus. So i don't think there is a system setting that allows to stop notifications when the app is closed and to reactivate them if the app is started.

Maybe you can send a feature request if that setting would make sense for this individual app. You can contact their mobile support team, find out how [on google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebay.mobile).